# jquery .append automatically renders closing tags

Tags: jquery, html, append

I am using .append to add html to a div.
But when I use .append the tags will also be closed.
For example the first line will render `<li></li>` instead of just `<li>`

How can this be fixed. Is there another method to render my nested UL/LI

**JavaScript**

```
$("#test_UL").append("<li>");
$("#test_UL").append("<a href='#'><span>link</span></a>");
$("#test_UL").append("<ul>");
//more stuff an foreach to render list items

$("#test_UL").append("</ul>");
$("#test_UL").append("</li>");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This same thing you have to do differently:

```
$('<li>',{
    html:'<a href="#"><span>link</span></a>'
}).appendTo('#test_UL');
```

---

Because when you pass any html string in the jQuery wrapper it is considered to create an element so it dynamically adds a closing tag if you don't put it. All these are same:

```
var html = $('<li>')
var html = $('<li/>') 
var html = $('<li></li>')
```

Actually behind the scenes jQuery uses `document.createElement()` method for it.

---

Or you can make a variable and concatenate the html strings and then just append it:

```
var html = '<li>';
    html += '<a href="#"><span>link</span></a>';

$('#test_UL').append(html);
```